# Infopath views as SharePoint forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

I made an Infopath form that has two views, Edit and Print, and published it to SharePoint.

The issue is that as you type a new entry, you can switch to the print view allowing you to print without the need to save the data into SharePoint.

I want to disable that, and I want the print view to be accessed only when Viewing an item from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dummy/hidden field. This field has a default value of 0. When a form is submitted, set this to 1. Now put a rule on form on load. The rule is that when dummy field is 1, the button is enabled and you can switch to Print view. The button is disabled when dummy field is 0 because the form is not yet submitted and preventing the user to get to Print View.

Comment: Sorry but im new to infopath, I understood what you wanted me to do but i have no clue on how to do it, could you give me some steps?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot teach you the step by step. Actually my answer is already a direct step on how to do it. Just to clarify, dummy field is a text box. Create a text box that we will call dummy field.

the rest of the steps are basic actions on rules. Please try discovering it.

Comment: i found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okgKJVOGr2o) that solved my problem :)
but thanks for the reply

Comment: good to hear. If you have time, you can try my suggestion.